# High resolution display desktop icon positioning

Tags: windows-10, desktop, icons, acer-aspire, high-resolution

I am using Acer Aspire S7-391 and I can't position icons to far right and to the bottom of my desktop.
I believe it has something to do with its resolution, which is 1920x1080.

I know I can position them if I disable `Align icons to grid` but I want them to snap to edges.
It happened in Windows 8.1 and now in 10.
I tried changing the resolution but it doesn't help.

Screenshot shows farthest I can put my icons.

[image: Desktop screenshot]

Screenshot shows farthest I can put my icons when I get them as tiny as possible.

[image: Desktop screenshot 2]

Intel display settings

[image: Intel control panel]

UPDATE:
I managed to get what I wanted originally by changing desktop icon spacing in `Registry editor` but in the process I found another problem which might be what's causing all this but will ask about it in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/961348/windows-shows-wrong-resolution-compared-to-display).

This is how my desktop looks now. I tweaked the spacing to my liking even though it's not perfectly correct and I will try resetting it to defaults if I manage to fix my resolution.

[image: Fixed desktop]

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested on a 2560x1440 and a 1920x1080 screen and I don't have this problem, I dont think it has nothing to do with the resolution, it seems that your icons are largen in proportion, try to hold ctrl and move the mouse wheel, make the icons smaller and then try to move them.
Your screen is 1080 but are you sure the computer is set to that resolution aswell?
Try updating your gpu drivers as last resource

Comment: Tried that earlier, forgot to write. Updated OP with another screenshot.
Updated to Intel HD graphics Windows 10 driver.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can position them if I disable Align icons to grid but I want
>   them to snap to edges.

You can't have align icons to grid but also not align icons to grid at the same time. Windows does not have a "snap to edge" feature.

As you've already discovered, this issue occurs because the default grid size does not match perfectly with your desktop resolution, so you've had to change it yourself. It is impossible to have a single grid size that perfectly matches every possible display, and auto-detect sometimes gets it wrong.

Where I've most often seen this occur is when you use or have previously used different resolutions and the grid size has "stuck" - or if you have multiple monitors with different resolutions as one grid size is used across all of them.